# form breaks when AppearanceRules used

Tags: wolfram-cloud, deployment

```
    CloudDeploy[
     FormFunction[
      {{{"y1", "Y-axis"} -> "Number",
        {"x1", "X-axis"} -> "Number"},
      {{"y2", "Y-axis"} -> "Number",
        {"x2", "X-axis"} -> "Number"}},
     Piecewise[
      {{"Country A has a comparative advantage in producing Y and 
         Country B has a comparative advantage in producing X", (#y1/#x1) >(#y2/#x2)},
       {"Country A has a comparative advantage in producing X and 
         Country B has a comparative advantage in producing Y", (#y1/#x1)<(#y2/#x2)},
       {"Neither Country has a comparative advantage", (#y1/#x1) == (#y2/#x2)}}] &, 
  AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> "Comparative Advantage Calculator"|>
]]
```

Comment: Please add more information to your post: explain exactly what it is that you want, perhaps by providing an example.  As it is, it is completely unclear what you want here.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this is a known bug and should not be put on hold.

Comment: @Christopher Unfortunately the Review Queue does not show answers so I did not see yours.  (I usually avoid the Queue for this reason but there were a lot in there tonight so I started cranking through them.)  The post above is not a question as written; please edit to to make in a question appropriate to your answer, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Storm Silva, please verify that my answer solves your problem. If it does, then we can edit of your question so that it will be removed from Hold.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug, which has been commented on [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/766072). The workaround is to define the appearance rules separately for each *formspec*:

```
CloudDeploy[
   FormFunction[{
      FormObject[{"A" -> "Number"},
         AppearanceRules -> <| "Title" -> "Title A" |>],
      FormObject[{"B" -> "Number"},
         AppearanceRules -> <| "Title" -> "Title B" |>] &},
      Identity],
   FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory, "MultipageFormAppearanceRules"}]]
```